# ¿Por qué se utiliza "facha" o "facho" como sinónimo coloquial de "fascista"?

Tags: coloquialismos, españa, adjetivos, argentina, italiano

En España es común llamar *facha* como sinónimo del adjetivo *fascista*. Así lo recoge el DLE:

> [**facha**<sup>3</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HSVIHQk|HSXn31v|HSa7yQO)
>   `Acort. del it. fascista.`
>
> 1. adj. despect. coloq. [fascista](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HexvkN9). Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.
> 2. adj. despect. coloq. De ideología política reaccionaria. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.

Donde:

> [**fascista**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HexvkN9)
>   `Del it. fascista.`
>
> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al fascismo.
> 2. adj. Partidario del fascismo. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.
> 3. adj. Excesivamente autoritario.

Si escucho la palabra [*fascista* en italiano en Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=it&tl=pt&text=fascista) oigo algo así como /faxista/, que queda algo lejos de /facha/. Por ello, ¿alguien sabe cuál fue la evolución del vocablo *fascista* hasta llegar a *facha*?

Nótese por cierto que también se usa *facho* en Hispanoamérica:

> [**facho, cha**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HSqwXYN)
>
> 1. adj. despect. coloq. Arg., Chile y Ur. **facha**<sup>3</sup>. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.
> 2. m. coloq. Cuba. robo (‖ acción de robar).

Comment: /fasʃista/ no está lejos de /fastʃista/  :-)  De hecho, en inglés cuando tenemos dos sonidos de este tipo (frecuente en plurals, como *tests*) comemos la /t/ intermedia.  Imagino que lo mismo pasa en italiano.

Comment: @guifa interesante! ¿Por lo que la palabra se formaría por la supresión del _ist_ interno? ¿Qué tan común es este cambio?

Comment: Lo de quitar una /t/ entre sonidos de tipo /s/ /ʃ/? será común imagino.  Lo de quitar la parte de *-ista* algo menos, aunque en castellano existe *progre* de *progresista* — no sería difícil de imaginar unos «monarquis» que son pro monarquía, o unos «republis» que son pro república.  La *a* final de *facha* pues no sé.

Comment: Hay que notar que el emblema fascista en Italia era el [*fascio*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascio), y que (hasta donde sé), se pronuncia  "faschio" (WP lo muestra como /faʃʃo/) y en Italia se ha usado como metonimia de "fascista". Así que a un fascista italiano se le puede llamar en italiano "fascio", que aún parece más similar a "facha". Que ya existiera la palabra "facha" anteriormente (aunque con otro significado) puede haber ayudado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se llama este fenómeno *síncopa*. Es más notable en la evolución de palabras latinas a español, pero a veces se pasa en palabras recientes también:

- vuestra merced > usted
- impecable > impeque
- facultativo > faculto
- bailador > bailaor
- fonolita > fonola
- fórmico > formo

Y *fascista* (que se pronuncia como "fachista") > [facha](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2v1YAAAAMAAJ&q=facha+fascista).